# which .net framework is suitable for windows 7 and later?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-7

Can I create an application that all versions of .NET frameworks can run ? and which .NET framework should I use ? (I'm targeting windows 7 and later up to windows 10 )

Comment: The latest.  The OS has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which .NET framework is installed on the machines. You should be totally safe with 3.5 version because [Windows 7 has it by default](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/).